# Integration and The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus

Is there an alternate way to answer this question, if anyone could please help.

[image]

The textbook answer it like this:

[image]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88651/for-continuous-function-f-prove-int-0x-left-int-0tfu-du

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By parts:

$$x-u\to -du$$

$$f(u)\to \int_0^u f(t)dt$$

Therefore:

$$\int_0^x f(u)(x-u)du=\left[(x-u)\int_0^u f(t)dt\right]_0^x+\int_0^x\int_0^u f(t)dt\;du$$

$$\int_0^x f(u)(x-u)du=\int_0^x\int_0^u f(t)dt\;du$$

This of course relies on $f$ being continuous.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Somehow your last comment seems to imply that continuity of $f$ is equivalent to integrability, which is clearly false; continuity is a stronger condition than integrability. You need continuity only to use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @NilsMatthes That is what meant, but I realise it was baldy put. Thanks.

Comment: Does this in itself prove that f is continuous, or not, I am confused now. Isn't this answer using the fundamental theorem?

Comment: @Dicky The continuity of $f$ is assumed. The use of the FTC is justified by the continuity of $f$ but does not prove it (and we do not need to prove it, since it is a given).

Comment: Oh yeah, maybe I should learn how to read, thanks the reply.

Answer (score 1):

For given $x>0$ consider the triangle $T:=\{(t,u)\ |\ 0\leq u\leq t\leq x\}$ in the $(t,u)$-plane and on $T$ the function $\phi(t,u):= f(u)$; see the following figure.

[image]

By Fubini's theorem we can compute the integral
$$J:=\int_T \phi(t,u)\ {\rm d}(t,u)$$
in two ways, namely as
$$J=\int_0^x\left(\int_u^x \phi(t,u)\ dt\right)\ du=\int_0^x\left(\int_u^x f(u)\ dt\right)\ du=\int_0^x f(u)(x-u)\  du$$
and as
$$J=\int_0^x\left(\int_0^t \phi(t,u)\ du\right)\ dt=\int_0^x\left(\int_0^t f(u)\ du\right)\ dt\ .$$